# How to preserve null in system.array - C#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, system.array

I got the first row of an excel sheet with the following code.

```
Excel.Range firstRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows[1];
var row = (System.Array) firstRow.Cells.Value;
List<object> Array = row.OfType<object>().ToList();
```

`row` consists of  null values.

Eg. [image]

**The problem is when it is converted in to list, all the null values are lost.**
(After this statement)

```
 List<object> Array = row.OfType<object>().ToList();
```

Eg. [image]

Any ideas how to prevent this from happening ?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Updated for clarity :)

Comment: @Chris: Updated to the correct code-snippet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From looking at what you are doing `Cast` would be more appropriate than `OfType`.

```
List<object> Array = myvalues.Cast<object>().ToList();
```

This should do what you want and basically just tell it that all objects should be cast to type object. This will preserve the null.

The reason for the difference is that `OfType` does a check for `current is TResult` before returning the cast object and of course `null is object` will return false and thus it gets dropped. The corollary of this is of course that `Cast` can throw exceptions if misused (eg `Cast<int>` on the above sample would throw an `InvalidCastException` whereas `OfType<int>` would just return the items that could be cast to ints.

**From:** [CAST AND OFTYPE](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/13/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-33-cast-and-oftype/)

> There’s one important case to consider where Cast will successfully
>   return a value and OfType will ignore it: null references (with a
>   nullable return type). In normal code, you can cast a null reference
>   to any nullable type (whether that’s a reference type or a nullable
>   value type). However, if you use the "is" C# operator with a null
>   value, it will always return false. Cast and OfType follow the same
>   rules, basically.

Comment: But if `object` is `System.Object` he could also use `OfType` since everything inherits from it. Well, [not quite everything](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Except that the type of `null` can not be determined when using `OfType`, and is therefore omitted.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: But the whole point is that `OfType` is removing his null whereas `Cast` doesn't...

Comment: @Chris: i didn't know that. Learned something new :) Why is that so?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Added in a note on that. Basically `Cast` doesn't bother doing a check of the type before casting (so will return casting exceptions if you aren't careful) whereas `OfType` does type checks which null doesn't agree with. And its always nice when I get to teach something to a person with over 180,000 rep. ;-)

Comment: @NiranjanKala: Thanks for the references. :)